# ImporError: No module named 'win32com' Python 3.4

Tags: python, module, win32com

Trying to execute an Excels macro from Python using this code:

```
import os, os.path
import win32com.client
if os.path.exists("ihm.xlsm"):
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("ihm.xlsm"))
    xl.Application.Run("ihm.xlsm!Module20.import_utilisateur_encours")
    xl.Application.Save()  # to save uncomment and delete the ", ReadOnly=1" part from the open function.
    xl.Application.Quit()  # Comment this out if your excel script closes
del xl
```

> ImportError: No module named 'win32com'

Already tried to `pip install pypiwin32` but I had to specify `--no-dependencies` and it's still not working. I seen that there are some troubles about win32 module with python 3.4.

I also found a forge .exe with multiple builds, but I cannot run it thanks to security restrictions in my office.

Please Help.

Comment: Yeah I think you need to build it yourself for windows then. Download the sources zip here: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32 and build it

Comment: Actually tried `python setup.py -install` giving me "Can't find a windows 8.1 sdk" **RuntimeError: Can't find the Windows SDK**... while running on a windows 7 os

Comment: Well you'd need to install the Windows SDK. That one however requires an admin user again. So maybe try to find another solution which does not require pywin32

Comment: Try install pywin32  `pip install pywin32`

Comment: Note that I've got a win32-ctypes module that I don't even know what it does

Answer (score 4):

Try to install pywin32

```
pip install pywin32
```

Comment: Network is bloking it, I can only download the package and make a local pip install

Comment: In that case you can refer https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32#building-from-source

Comment: After downloading from git you can use 
`python setup.py install` to install the package.

Comment: Can't find a windows 8.1 sdk
RuntimeError : Can't find the Windows SDK

The point is that I'm running on a Windows 7 os

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into xlwings? That will do what you need it to do and has a simpler interface.

```
import xlwings as xw
app = xw.App()
macro_result = app.macro('macro_name')
```

docs are [here](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html)

Comment: Downloaded the package and did a local `pip install` of it but it seems that something is wrong again :
> warning : no files found matching '*' under directory 'docs' 
and then it's trying to pip install again from pypi